# Debouncing user input from a library callback

Tags: angular, observable, debouncing

I am using [ng2-ace-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace-editor) in my Angular 2 application and I want to provide a very simple validation on user input, actually it would be more of a small print warning (based on user-provided text) below the text area rather than a true validation.

As we know the best practice is to debounce the input coming from an event, as in:

```
Observable.fromEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .map(() => myTextArea.value)
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged();
```

However, the only output/callback that ng2-ace-editor provides is @Output `(textChanged)` which is generated from the library's `editor.on('change', fn)` which appears not to be using any kind of debounce.

Hence my question: what would be the best a man could get with such API? Would the below code (repetitive calling `Observable.from` with incoming values) make any sense?

**html**

```
(textChanged)="myTextChanged($event)"
```

**ts:**

```
myTextChanged($event){
    Observable.from([$event])
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(text => this.myValidation(text));
}

myValidation(){
    /* analyze the input and show/hide a warning */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to have something that you can subscribe to, then push the text change events onto it. For example:

```ts
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    textChange = new Subject<string>();

    ngOnInit() {
      this.textChange
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(text => this.myValidation(text));
    }

    myTextChanged($event) {
        this.textChange.next($event);
    }

    ...

}
```

This means you set up the subscription only once, in `ngOnInit`, and simplifies the `myTextChanged` method to just broadcast the new change into the subject's observable stream.

You could also use a `ViewChild` to get more direct access to the child emitter, see e.g. [Component Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html).